# Reading Unicode encoded characters into my application

Tags: c#, unicode

I have an application that when run will display correctly all Unicode encoded characters (OK it is made that way). These data will be stored in a database file. And i write an application to  read all of them out, but it can't be read correctly as expected. Languages like Japanese, Chinese, Korean are fine, only languages like Vietnamese, German Dutch etc any of which with dots or strokes on top of characters are unable to get displayed concisely at all. Thank you for any help.

[**UPDATE**]

Well thank you, I don't think I need anymore of East and Asia languages to be installed, as they are all in my computer system already. Only they are unable to display in my created application but are shown up just fine in the application that uses the database to store and retrieve them. For example, long ago when the yahoo messenger was monolingual, only English can be displayed but later on the it was added with other dlls to display correctly other characters from other languages. Settings to reading other languages are no longer needed to deal with dlls. Supposing that the current messenger can read English, Japanese, Chinese via different inputs from keyboard, and my application called messengerreader is to read those inputs. The messenger works fine with those inputs whilst my messengerreader is unable to figure out some languages as I mentioned above. What should or can I do now to make them all work ? I am thankful for any help.

[**UPDATE again**]

Ok, an easy example i can think up right now on my application that I need to read in a username that is displayed correctly as "Lê Sao" in the original application. My application displays some odd characters after 'L'.

```
public struct Username
{
   public string username;
}

IEnumerable<Username> Getuser(string tableName)
{
   Datatable dt=ReadDB(tableName);
   List<Username> lst=new List<Username>();

   lst.Add(new Username(){username=dt.Rows[0]['username']});
   return lst.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Which kind of unicode ? UTF-8 ? UTF-16 LE/BE ? UTF832 ?

Comment: Which OS are you on ? You may need to install support for east asian languages.

Comment: Ok. You should give more precision on how you read your input. Is it a `DllImport` call, socket communication ... And which character encoding. Does the documentation of your source specifies the encoding ? Are you sure it's UTF ? Which variant (there are several kinds of UTF encodings) ... At stage showing a bit of code of the interfacing between you and the other program will help.

Comment: How is does it 'not' work? Does it throw and error or does it just not display the text. What font are you trying to display the text with?

Comment: What is the data type of your database column?

Comment: How are you creating your database connection and how are you executing the query?

Comment: J.N. Wouldn't that only install suitable fonts? I doubt Unicode data processing has to rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you dump out the hex for the Username string, add a method like this to the

```
public string UserNameAsHexDump  {
        get
        {

            char[] ca = username.ToCharArray();

            string output = "";
            foreach (char c in ca)
            {
                output += string.Format("{0} - {1:X4}\r\n", c, (uint)c);
            }

            return output;

        }
    }
```

copy the result out and let us see the raw data,  "Lê Sao" sample gives:

```
L - 004C
ê - 00EA
  - 0020
S - 0053
a - 0061
o - 006F
```

from that SO can probably give you an answer